# How to group column on the basis of level

Tags: sql-server

I have a table structure and some sample data in it, which is like below.

```
CREATE TABLE COA
(
COACode NVARCHAR(50),
COATitle VARCHAR(50),
)

INSERT INTO COA VALUES (01, 'Expense');
INSERT INTO COA VALUES (01-01, 'Expense');
INSERT INTO COA VALUES (01-01-01, 'Expense');
INSERT INTO COA VALUES (01-01-02, 'Expense');
INSERT INTO COA VALUES (01-02, 'Expense');
INSERT INTO COA VALUES (01-02-01, 'Expense');
INSERT INTO COA VALUES (01-02-02, 'Expense');
```

The expected output I am looking for is something like this.

```
COACode     COACode     COACode     COATitle
01                                  Expense
            01-01                   Expense
                        01-01-01    Expense
                        01-01-02    Expense
            01-02                   Expense
                        01-02-01    Expense
                        01-02-02    Expense
```

The query needs to be dynamic, like as this is level 3 COACode but could be more or less as well. So if user inserts COACode with more level it should insert it in next column but if it comes with same COACode level then it's fine.

Comment: Could you include another column to your table, which will be the parent of the COACode? So you will always store one code per column. For example the entry 01-01-01 will be : (01,0), (01,01), (01,01)

Comment: Do you have the possibility to change the table structure like as add column "COAParentCode"

Comment: @EsatARSLAN Yes ParentCode could be added in the structure

Answer (score 0):

May be you can do like this

```
CREATE TABLE COA
(
COACode NVARCHAR(50),
ParentCode NVARCHAR(50),
COATitle VARCHAR(50),
)

INSERT INTO COA VALUES ('01', NULL,'Expense');
INSERT INTO COA VALUES ('01-01', '01','Expense');
INSERT INTO COA VALUES ('01-01-01','01-01' ,'Expense');
INSERT INTO COA VALUES ('01-01-02','01-01', 'Expense');
INSERT INTO COA VALUES ('01-02', '01','Expense');
INSERT INTO COA VALUES ('01-02-01','01-02' ,'Expense');
INSERT INTO COA VALUES ('01-02-02','01-02' ,'Expense');

;WITH x AS
(
    -- anchor:
    SELECT COACode, COATitle, ParentCode, [level] = 0
    FROM COA WHERE ParentCode IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    -- recursive:
    SELECT t.COACode, t.COATitle, t.ParentCode, [level] = x.[level] + 1
    FROM x INNER JOIN COA AS t
    ON t.ParentCode = x.COACode
)
SELECT COACode, COATitle, ParentCode, [level] FROM x
ORDER BY [level]
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 32);
```

Comment: Would you like to paste the output here ?

Comment: This output is nothing like the expected I have paste.